# Blender ignores edge flow

Tags: edges

For some reason after I cut some faces with the knife tool, Blender doesn't recognize the new edge flow, see pictures. There are no duplicates vertices or edges, I checked. Although if I delete the vertex in the middle and reconnect everything, suddenly Blender understands the flow... Is there a way to recalculate the edge flow or something like that? Thank you

[image]

As you can see, after simply deleting the vertex marked in red, and then closing the hole, Blender recognizes the faces as being part of a loop, which wasn't the case before. So the question is, is there a way to make Blender understand the flow without having to delete a vertex and joining the geometry again?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "edge flow"? You've only shown one image, but I'm guessing that you're trying to loop cut across a face which has more than four vertices which isn't permitted in Blender.

Comment: You may have some inner faces or overlapping vertices, it would explain why the edge loop can't cut the quad. Could you please share the part where you meet the problem and trace the edge loop you would like with the annotation tool?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you might be misunderstanding the edge flow. Edge ring consists of these edges:

[image]

You can insert an edge loop to those edges:

[image]

The edge loop does not turn up like your sketch shows, it would have to make a triangle or insert a vertex other way and edge loops are not that. If I misunderstood and what you show is the cut made with the knife tool, then there is no edge ring that you could insert an edge loop to. This thing here breaks any edge flow:

[image]

See [the documentation about edge rings and loops](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) for more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I think it's rather a loopcut that is seen by transparency, cutting off some quads that are behind the object

Comment: Yes Martynas its the loopcut seen in transparency